# Writing regex for number starting with 105 and above or number which are greater that 105

Tags: regex

Hey Guys I want to get regex for numbers which are greater than `105` and above for all 3 digit number and they can be follow by 3 or 2 decimal like `105.1` ,`109.11` like this.

I tried with

```
^\s*((105|\d{3,})\.\d+)\s*$
```

but no luck

Comment: So, the number should be from `105` to `999`? "follow by 3 or 2 decimal" - `109.123` is valid, isn't it? Leading/trailing whitespace is allowed, right?

Comment: [`^(?:10[5-9]|1[1-9][0-9]|[2-9][0-9]{2})(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?$`](https://regex101.com/r/F58mCJ/1). **Edit:** Didn't notice the "3 or 2 decimals". This is for 1 or 2 decimals. Replace `{1,2}` with `{2,3}` (or `{1,3}` if you also want to support one decimal).

Comment: You can use some online tool like [regex-range.com](https://www.regex-range.com/) - I'd come up with something like [`^(?:10[5-9]|1[1-9]\d|[2-9]\d{2})(?:\.\d+)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/JiKMbk/1) using this for your requirements.

Comment: Please do not roll back edits on your post that fix formatting issues.